# Plot a grid of images retrieved via url in Python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, urllib

How does one display a grid of images using Matplotlib and images retrieved over the network?

I tried the following

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import urllib.request

a_url = 'https://via.placeholder.com/255x255'

# fetch image from placeholder.com
data = urllib.request.urlopen(a_url).read()
np_arr = np.frombuffer(data)

plt.plot(np_arr)

'''
images = [data]
print(type(data))

plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
columns = 5
for i, image in enumerate(images):
    plt.subplot(len(images) / columns + 1, columns, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(image)
'''
```

but get the error `buffer size must be a multiple of element size`

Comment: You pass some raw PNG bytes to frombuffer(). Did you maybe want to have a PNG decoder turn them into pixels first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

solution

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a_url = 'https://via.placeholder.com/255x255'

data = plt.imread(a_url)
images = [data for _ in range(13)]

plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
columns = 5
for i, image in enumerate(images):
    plt.subplot(len(images) / columns + 1, columns, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(image)
```

interactive link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a-toRZ9rOL-_BwBuD1kYdAgZnVj25C4v/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you can directly retrieve images with `plt.imread`and a url, and then show it with `plt.imshow`.